# Setting header status from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, http-status-codes

I have a view page `errors/401`. This is dedicated for displaying errors with 401 status, and I always want to render that page with status 401. In the controller that renders that page, I write like

```
render "error/401", status: 401
```

I feel this is redundant. Since this page is always rendered with a particular status, I want to specify the status within the view page, not mention it in the controller, and get the same result. I just want to write:

```
render "error/401"
```

Is this possible?

Comment: i'm not sure if it's possible but since you're using controller/view to return a custom error page.. rails controller will always add `status: 200` to your response header unless you mention otherwise

Comment: No, because your server processes the request/response - which in this case is controller. Controller is suppose to take care of your response and response's request headers which includes the status. You're not suppose to do so in your views. That being said, you can create this file as public/401.html, and while you just say `status: 401` web server will serve public/401.html. However, this 401.html will be a static HTML file and will not be able to parse any ruby code inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to specify the status within the view page, not mention it in the controller

It doesn't belong to your view. A template should output characters, not HTTP status codes.

> I feel this is redundant.

It is. Rails uses exceptions to signal and handle such errors, e.g. a missing record results in a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception which in turn renders a 404 page.

You could do the same by defining a `NotAuthorised` error that is handed via [`rescue_from`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from) in your `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  class NotAuthorised < StandardError; end

  rescue_from NotAuthorised do |exception|
    render 'error/401', status: 401
  end
end
```

From another controller:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def index
    raise NotAuthorised
  end
end
```